# How to wake up RecursiveTask<V> with notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I cannot figure it out, how can I wake up **RecursiveTasks**, invoked by **ForkJoinPool**, when these tasks are on hold by **wait** method. Here is my simple example with the method *MainRecursionClass.resume* which is incorrect (does not wakes up RecursiveTasks).

```
public class Program {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Program p = new Program();
      final MainRecursionClass mrc = p.new MainRecursionClass();

      //Thread outputs integers to simulate work
      new Thread() {
         public void run() {
            mrc.doJob();
         }
      }.start();

      //Thread performs wait and notify on MainRecursionClass object
      p.new PauseResume(mrc).start();
   }

/**
 * 
 * This class performs suspend and resume operations to the MainRecursionClass class object
 *
 */
   private class PauseResume extends Thread {
      private MainRecursionClass rv;

      public PauseResume(MainRecursionClass rv) {
         this.rv = rv;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
         while(!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
               sleep(4000);

               rv.suspend();
               sleep(8000);

               rv.resume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private class MainRecursionClass {
      private boolean pause = false;
      private MyRecursive rv;

      public void doJob() {
         rv = new MyRecursive(0, 100000);
         ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();      
         pool.invoke(rv);
      }

      public void suspend() {
         pause = true;

         System.out.println("Suspended");
      }

      /**
       * This method is incorrect. It should wake up all MyRecursive instances to continue their work.
       */
      public synchronized void resume() {
         pause = false;
         notifyAll();

         System.out.println("Resumed");
      }

      private class MyRecursive extends RecursiveTask<Object> {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
         private int start;
         private int length;
         private int threshold = 15;

         public MyRecursive(int start, int length) {
            super();
            this.start = start;
            this.length = length;
         }

         protected void computeDirectly() throws Exception {
            for (int index = start; index < start + length; index++) {
               //PAUSE
               synchronized (this) {
                  try {
                     while(pause) {
                        wait();
                     }
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
               }
               //PAUSE

               //some output to simulate work...
               System.out.println(index);

               Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
         }

         /**
          * Recursion
          */
         @Override
         protected Object compute() {
            if (length <= threshold) {
               try {
                  computeDirectly();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  return e;
               }

               return null;
            }

            int split = length / 2;

            invokeAll(new MyRecursive(start, split),
                      new MyRecursive(start + split, length - split));

            return null;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to `notify()` the `MyRecursive` instance.

Comment: Do you mean I have to do `notify();` on all `MyRecursive` instances, which will be created recursively? FYI: I tried to change `resume()` method like this: `rv.notify();` and I got `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: You need to understand what `synchronized`, `wait`, and `notify` do. If you call `wait()` on an object, here `this.wait()`, then the current `Thread` will be blocked until another `Thread` calls `notify` on the same instance.

Comment: I changed `resume()` method like this: `for(MyRecursive mr : list) { mr.notify(); }`, but like I mentioned before, I got `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` on `mr.notify()` invocation. Can you help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to wait and notify on the same instance. The setting of `pause` and the notify are on the `MainRecursionClass` instance, whereas the wait calls are on the `MyRecursive` instances. Change the wait calls to be something like `MainRecursionClass.this.wait()`.

Comment: Thank you @StuartMarks for advice, however, it was incorrect. I still have to call `wait` on `MyRecursive`, because the real work is done there, so calling `MainRecursionClass.this.wait()` won't stop the executions. Fortunately your advice showed me a solution: I've implemented method `public synchronized void resume() { notify(); }` in `MyRecursive` and call it on every instance of this class. Now execution pauses and resumes correctly.

Comment: @polis you should post your solution as an answer and accept it; this will close the question, and might help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to this solution: I created `List<MyRecursive> list = new ArrayList<>();` object in `MainRecursionClass` and added every `MyRecursive` instance, created recursively, in the `list`. The class `MyRecursive` has new method:

```
public synchronized void resume() {
   notify();
}
```

When, the method `MainRecursionClass.resume()`, which wakes up the threads, looks like this:

```
public void resume() {
   System.out.println("Resumed");

   pause = false;
   for(MyRecursive mr : list) {
      if(mr != null)
         mr.resume();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use wait/notify in the tasks running on a thread pool. If your pool is bounded, then it may cause thread starvation (a form of deadlock). If it is unbounded, too many threads can be created and main memory exhausted.

Instead, you should split your task in 2 (or more) and start subtasks according to their starting conditions. When you want a task to `wait()`, then refactor it so that current subtask exits, and next subtask is prepared to run.

Comment: My pool is bounded. The flag _pause_ suspends all threads in a pool and no new threads are created when `pause = true`.